# Appium IOS Inspector without id or anything unique

Tags: ios, appium, inspector

I'm trying (painfully) to access an iphone through appium

I finally managed to launch the app through appium but now I have an issue with the inspector.

Almost everything is a "UIACollectionCell" and the final objects for a example like a text don't have any id or content desc, it's just :

```
name = "mytext"
type = statictext
value = "mytext"
label = "mytext"
```

and then the xpath that apparently have all the object of the page (the visible on the screen and the non visible)
and looks something like

```
//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIScrollView[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[2]/UIAStaticText[2]
```

is this normal ? do I still need to change parameter in the plist of the app or in the build settings or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

In Appium, UIACollectionCell and UIAStaticText are ClassNames. name is AccessibilityId. So you can use className or accessibilityID or xPath.

Ex:

```
driver.findElementByClassName("UIACollectionCell").click();
driver.findElementByAccesiblityId("mytext").click();
driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIScrollView[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[2]/UIAStaticText[2]
").click();
```